# How to write test cases for value changes for a formControl

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

```
app.component.ts

poNbrsFieldCount = 0;


this.form.controls.po.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      Iif (value) this.poNbrsFieldCount = value.length;
    });
```

How to write testcases for valueChanges in formControl. Can i directly repeat the same code in spec file also?

Answer (score 0):

you can subscribe to event changes of a specific formControl like this

```
this.myForm.get('yourformControlName').valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
   console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: but this is not test case